# Export Emojies and Latin extended charaters on same CSV

Tags: c#, csv, utf-8, export

Need to export data set as a CSV using C#, below exports everything (including emojis) correctly except Latin extended characters. (Ex. aesthetic d**é**cor)

```
 byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvData.ToString());
 return File(bytes, "text/csv", "MyFile.csv");
```

What is the correct C# function I should use?

Comment: We can just assume File is a Controller method in asp.net.  If it looks wrong on the recipients side i would suggest you first look what the recipient does with it.

Comment: @Ralf It just downloads and is used for reporting purposes. There is one column with Product Description, on which there are Latin extended characters and Emojis. They need to be present on the exported CSV.

Comment: And how do you look at them on the clientside? Maybe there is the problem and not what you return here. 2 mayor things that can go wrong here. csvData.ToString() delivers it wrong or the client does look at it wrong.

Comment: @Ralf Once it is exported, will get imported into the system via the browser.